Processing a form in app-router as client side and not server side
I'm trying to execute a login with next.js app router. I started with this:
export default function Login(){
  async function LoginExecute(prevState, frmData){
    'use server'
    try{
      const userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, frmData.get('email'), frmData.get('password'));
      const idToken = await userCredential.user.getIdToken();

      await signIn("credentials", {
        email: frmData.get('email'),
        idToken,
        redirect: false,
      });
    }
    catch(error){
      console.log(error)
      throw new Error('Firebase error')
    }
  }  
  return <LoginFrm action={LoginExecute} />
}

Nothing seem to work. It kept saying the signIn method needed to be executed on the client and not the server and I didn't find anyway to do that. I kept getting error messages that once I'm using action, that it must be server processed.
So what I did to get it working was a normal API rest call as with page-router or react&node:
export default function Login(){  
  return <LoginFrm />
}

LoginForm
'use client'
const handlerSubmit=async(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    try {
        const response = await fetch('/api/auth/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
        });

        const data = await response.json();
        const signInResult = await signIn("credentials", {
            email,
            idToken: data.idToken,
            redirect: false,
        });
        router.push('/'); // Redirect to the homepage or another page after successful login
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Login failed:', error);
    }
}

return (
<>
    <form onSubmit={handlerSubmit}  >

My question: is this good code design with app-router principles? i.e. any type of client processing of a form must be done with an API rest call (and saving state in useState or useRef) rather than server processing (use server)? Because I couldn't use / take advantage of action frmData here to retrieve all the fields in the form.
E.g. lets say I have to display an error message (which is client), will that also have to be done as API call or could I do it as server processing?
